# Problem detected by xampp, tomcat not running

Tags: tomcat, xampp

Am actually new to xampp, but whenever I launch the xampp control panel I get this error. Please I really need help here.

This is the error:

Problem detected!
Port 8080 in use by "C:/xampp/apache/bin/httpd.exe"!
Tomcat will not start without the configured port free! 
You need to uninstall /disable/configure the blocking applicantion or reconfigure tomcat and the control panel to listen on a different port.

Please am confused here,  any help?

Comment: *`"You need to uninstall /disable/configure the blocking application or reconfigure tomcat and the control panel to listen on a different port."`* - What's the confusion?

Comment: Basically, one port can only be used by one application, your tomcat tried to use port 8080 but it already occupied by Apache web server. You need to either: 1) stop apache so tomcat can use port 8080 2) config apache so that it uses another port 3) config tomcat so it uses a different port.